# pdfminer: extract only text according to font size

Tags: python-3.x, text-parsing, text-extraction, pdfminer, pdf-scraping

I only want to extract text that has font size `9.800000000000068` and `10.000000000000057` from my pdf files.
The code below returns a list of the font size of each text block and its characters for one pdf file.

```
Extract_Data=[]
for page_layout in extract_pages(path):
    print(page_layout)
    for element in page_layout:
        if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
            for text_line in element:
                for character in text_line:
                    if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                        Font_size=character.size
            Extract_Data.append([Font_size,(element.get_text())])
```

gives me an `Extract_Data` list with the various font sizes

```
[[9.800000000000068, 'aaa\n'], [11.0, 'dffg\n'], [10.000000000000057, 'bbb\n'], [10.0, 'hs\n'], [8.0, '2\n']]
```

example: font size `10.000000000000057`

```
Extract_Data=[]
for page_layout in extract_pages(path):
    print(page_layout)
    for element in page_layout:
        if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
            for text_line in element:
                for character in text_line:
                    if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                        if character.size == '10.000000000000057':
                            element.get_text()
                Extract_Data.append(element.get_text())
                Data = ''.join(map(str, Extract_Data))
```

gives me a `Data` list with all of the text. How can i make it only extract font size `'10.000000000000057'` characters?

```
['aaa\ndffg\nbbb\nhs\n2\n']
```

I also want to integrate into a function that does this for multiple files resulting in a pandas df that has one row for each pdf.
Desired output: `[['aaa\n bbb\n']]`. Convertin pixels to points (`int(character.size) * 72 / 96`) as suggested eksewhere did not help. Maybe this has something to do with this? https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/202

This is the function it would be integrated later on:

```
directory = 'C:/Users/Sample/'
resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if not file.endswith(".pdf"):
        continue
    fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    device = PDFPageAggregator(manager, laparams=params)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, device)
    device = TextConverter(interpreter, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
    params = LAParams(detect_vertical=True, all_texts=True)
    elements = []
    with open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'rb') as fh:
        parser = PDFParser(fh)
        document = PDFDocument(parser, '')
        if not document.is_extractable:
            raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

        for page in enumerate (PDFPage.create_pages(document)):
            for element in page:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pdfminer is the wrong tool for that.

Use pdfplumber (which uses pdfminer under the hood) instead https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber, because it has utility functions for filtering out objects (eg. based on font size as you're trying to do), whereas pdfminer is primarily for getting all text.

```py
import pdfplumber

def get_filtered_text(file_to_parse: str) -> str:
    with pdfplumber.open(file_to_parse) as pdf: 
        text = pdf.pages[0]
        clean_text = text.filter(lambda obj: not (obj["object_type"] == "char" and obj["size"] != 9))
        print(clean_text.extract_text())

get_filtered_text("./my_pdf.pdf")
```

The example above I've shown is easier than yours because it just checks for font size 9.0, and you have

> 9.800000000000068 and 10.000000000000057

so the obj["size"] condition will be more complex in your case

`obj["size"]` has the datatype `Decimal` (`from decimal import Decimal`) so you probably will have to do something like `obj["size"].compare(Decimal(9.80000000068)) == 0`

Comment: Pdfplumber is built on top of pdfminer.six. from that point of view, this comment is misleading.